# post data with a variable name use jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('i.icon-angle-up').on('click', function() {
    var data = {$(this).attr('name') : 'asc')}
    $.post('', data, function() {
        window.location.reload();
    });
});
```

i want post some data to server,but the name of the data comes from a variable($(this).attr('name')), how can i do?

i have tried

```
$.post('', {"$(this).attr('name')" : 'asc')}, function() {
        window.location.reload();
    });
```

but it don't go well.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key of an object cannot be dynamic, in that case you need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to create the object.

Try

```
var data = {};
data[$(this).attr('name')] = 'asc'
$.post('', data, function() {
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

other option is to use an object with eval (evil):

```
var data = {};
eval('data.' + $(this).attr('name') + ' = \'asc\'');
```